# radio telescope programs

Tags: internet-radio

I could not find one dealing with this.  I was wondering if there is any radio telescope programs available for the Ubuntu 14.04, and if not how would I go about writing one?  I am using a D.N. dish that is about 5-10yrs old, and planning to run it on a Toshiba Satalitte with an AMD E1 64bit system with Win8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 running in a virtual machine.

Comment: Are you talking about control software (steering/tracking/stabilization)? or data acquisition? or image processing/mapping? what kind of interface(s) does the dish provide?

Comment: The acquisition of the data, as well as processing/mapping to read the data. about the dish not 100% sure, i know it is capable of the new hd streaming tv channels.

Comment: Check out [distroastro.org](http://www.distroastro.org/). This is a distro for astronomy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GCX is what you are looking for:

> GCX: Astronomical image processing and photometry
>
> Gcx is an astronomical image processing and data reduction tool, with an easy to use graphical user interface. It provides a complete set of data reduction functions for CCD photometry, with frame WCS fitting, automatic star identification, aperture photometry of target and standard stars, single-frame ensemble photometry solution finding, multi-frame color coefficient fitting, extinction coefficient fitting, and all-sky photometry; as well as general-purpose astronomical image processing functions (bias, dark, flat, frame alignment and stacking); It can function as a FITS viewer.
>
> The program can control CCD cameras and telescopes, and implement automatic observation scripting. Cameras are controlled through a hardware-specific server, to which gcx connects through a TCP socket. It generates FITS files with comprehensive header information.

A list of possible candidates are on [Ubuntu's website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuScience/Astronomy), oddly enough. Apparently this sort of thing is in demand!